Zsh shell automatically converts into Docker interactive shell
I pushed some changes from my code into my GitHub repository. Now, after trying to rebuild my docker image, I'm trying to run some commands and my zsh shell automatically converts into a docker image shell. Because of this misconfiguration, I am unable to run commands unless I open a separate terminal.
I ran some codes "alias Docker=/usr/local/bin/docker", and even tried going to settings and changing the integrated terminal to external to no success.

Remember that Stack Overflow questions must be programming-related; also see the [help/on-topic].  Questions about using Unix shells might be more appropriate on another site like [unix.se].

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
